# ArcScene 2D export

Tags: export, arcscene, resolution, dimensions

I'm submitting a paper to PlosOne, and have been using ArcScene to produce my 3D mapping. However, I'm struggling to comprehend quite how to meet their image requirements (http://www.plosone.org/static/figureSpecifications#resolution)

They require images to be between 300-600ppi and 6.83 inches wide in TIFF format. I just can't get my head around what settings I need to use to set the resolution, width, height and view size parameters within the 2D export option.

Any suggestions?

It can't just be me who has these issues, with ArcScenes 2D export issues but have had little luck searching through previous questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inches is an irrelevant measure for digial products, the only measure that makes any sense is pixels.

However they've given you both pieces of information: 300 to 600 ppi and 8.63 inches. So on the lower end 300 * 8.63 = 2589 pixels and 600 * 8.63 = 5178 at the upper end.

Depending on the units for your width and height, if the units are pixels you already have the numbers, if it is in metres then it depends on your scale and similar to your view size.

Comment: The PLoS page says 2049 pixels. I think ppi is points per inch, not pixels per inch.

Comment: there's 72 points to an inch. Unless you're trying to say point features per square inch - at what scale?

Comment: I think the issue is that its 300*6.83 which does equal 2049 as PlosOne suggest. In order to set my export within ArcScene as 2049 pixels wide, I have to set the dpi as 62. Does that seem right?

Comment: Sorry, I transposed the figures and used 8.63 instead of 6.83. The end DPI is a tag in the TIFF file which is an instruction to consumers of the ungeoreferenced TIFF on how to print the image. Web resolution is generally agreed to be 72DPI. If the numbers come out to 62 then that is the answer based on your extent and scale which sounds fine to me. I have only once encountered a client that needed the DPI tag set and we had to do that in Photoshop as the ESRI export simply did not set that tag as it's meaningless for geolocated data.